ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rDNA’ in my Mac OS 14.6 Intel Chip
I tried installating RDNA package from https://github.com/leifeld/dna in my Mac Intel Chip MacOS 14.6 and this is the error I get:
I have latest R and RStudio.
> remotes::install_github("leifeld/dna/rDNA/rDNA@*release",INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
Downloading GitHub repo leifeld/dna@v3.0.11
Running `R CMD build`...
* checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/_c/958ppy910tbbylkv9rxjfv340000gn/T/Rtmpft60IM/remotes1bb13ef7aa06/leifeld-dna-8da39b8/rDNA/rDNA/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘rDNA’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building ‘rDNA_3.0.11.tar.gz’
* installing *source* package ‘rDNA’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
sh: line 1:  8393 Killed: 9               R_TESTS= '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-save --no-restore --no-echo 2>&1 < '/var/folders/_c/958ppy910tbbylkv9rxjfv340000gn/T//RtmpwHn0To/file20c418f42922'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rDNA’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-x86_64/Resources/library/rDNA’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/_c/958ppy910tbbylkv9rxjfv340000gn/T//Rtmpft60IM/file1bb175bb9035/rDNA_3.0.11.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I tried installating RDNA package from https://github.com/leifeld/dna in my Mac Intel Chip MacOS 14.6 and this is the error I get:
I have latest R and RStudio.

Do you have installed the Imports? https://github.com/leifeld/dna/blob/master/rDNA/rDNA/DESCRIPTION
